# How to understand transition probabilities from Durrett.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, markov-chains

[image]

I understand his definition of transition probability but I do not understand his integral notation. I know that if we fix the first component of the transition probability we get a probability measure. However, how does he pick the $x_0,x_1,..,x_{n-1}$ points used in determining the measures.

The second issue I have is more measure theoretic. He defined the finite dimensional distributions on the cylinder cells only but how is that sufficient to determine a finite dimensional distribution on the product sigma-algebra. Are we using Caratheodary extension theorem here. i.e. cylinder cells can form an algebra over which the definition given is a pre-measure which can be extended. If so, is the definition given just the product measure given by $\mu \otimes p(x_0,.)\otimes...\otimes p(x_{n-1},.)$?

Answer (score 1):

The $x_n$ are chosen by $X_n$. Plug $\omega$ into $X_n$ at time n.  This gives you $x_n$ which you use “choose” your probability measure for the next time.

It’s a little weird because the image of $X_n$ might be a proper subset of S.  So there could be $x_n$ that give probability measures that have nothing to do with $\Omega$.  But we will never use those.  They are a technicality.

What you propose for your second question seems reasonable, but is complicated by the fact that we need a possibly unique probability measure for each sample path of the random variable.  Will have to think about that bit. I usually just think of it as “conditioning” and the multiplication rule.